# Can I have more than one data-rule attribute?

Tags: php, html

Can I have more than one data-rule attribute? I have the contact form where some of the fields already have a "data-rule" (e.g., equal to their name), and I need to make those fields required.

can I add here

```
<input class="form-control input-phone" type="text" name="phone" data-rule="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone (with country code) or Skype">
```

`data-rule="required"` if there are already `data-rule="phone"`

Comment: use the required attribute

Comment: I mean, can I add here - "<input class="form-control input-phone" type="text" name="phone" data-rule="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone (with country code) or Skype">" - data-rule="required" if there are already  data-rule="phone" ?

Comment: what library are you using, data-rule is not a html5 attribute

Comment: add info from comment

Comment: this question is missing a tag, it sounds like the `data-rule` attribute is specific to some library, not a HTML standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things -

1. Add `required` property in the html tag.
2. Add `data-*` rule in your html tag and validate it using JavaScript.

And yes you can add multiple data-* rule. Just make sure they all don't have same name.

#### This is valid -

```
<input type="text" data-required="true" data-id="3" required>
```

#### This is not useful -

```
<input type="text" data-required="true" data-id="3" data-id="5" required>
```

If you do this, the first attribute encountered will always persist its value.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet would be beneficial in cases like this, but if you're using standard form like

```
<form>
     <input type="text" required />
     <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

required tag should not let empty values to be submitted. You can also use

```
required="required"
```

if not using HTML5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would be 
`<input class="form-control input-phone" type="text" name="phone" data-rule="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone (with country code) or Skype" required>` 
or

`<input class="form-control input-phone" type="text" name="phone" data-rule="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone (with country code) or Skype" required="required">`